# Removing line break in CSV output

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am converting an ASN IDOC from SAP to CSV format but want to get rid of an empty line that is occuring between the header and the content.

My code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>    

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="printHeader"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="DELVRY05/IDOC/E1EDL20/E1EDL24[LFIMG &gt; 0]"/>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="printHeader">
        <xsl:text>ProductCode,Description,Invoice,Invoice Date,Batch,Expires,Barcode,Quantity&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="E1EDL24">  
        <xsl:value-of select="MATNR"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ARKTX"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text><!--Invoice is empty-->
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text><!--Invoice date is empty-->
        <xsl:value-of select="CHARG"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="VFDAT"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="EAN11"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text><!--Barcode-->
        <xsl:value-of select="LFIMG"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The CSV output:[image: Row 2 is blank and I need to remove it.]

Row 2 is blank and I need to remove it, can someone help please?

Thank you.

Comment: You should have posted an input sample to allow us to reproduce the problem so that we can see where the white space comes from. You could start by adding `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Hy Jack,

Maybe it's because of the

`&#10;`

at the end of this line :

```
<xsl:text>ProductCode,Description,Invoice,Invoice Date,Batch,Expires,Barcode,Quantity&#10;</xsl:text>
```

?